# Unable to run blazor assembly project with hot reload feature enabled (.net 6 preview 5)

Tags: blazor-webassembly, hot-reload

After installation net6 preview 3 and setting up the project to use net6 I have changed the launchSettings.json and added  `"hotReloadProfile": "blazorwasm"` configuration.

When I run `dotnet watch` projects starts but I an unable to open the application because of error on client side (dotnet.6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5.js):

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:5555/_framework/blazor-hotreload.js
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:5555/_framework/blazor-hotreload.js)
 ---> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:5555/_framework/blazor-hotreload.js
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:5555/_framework/blazor-hotreload.js
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.<InvokeAsync>d__15`1[[Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSObjectReference, Microsoft.JSInterop, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.JSInterop.dll:token 0x600008f+0x154
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.HotReload.WebAssemblyHotReload.InitializeAsync() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll:token 0x6000098+0xc6
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHost.RunAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken, WebAssemblyCultureProvider cultureProvider) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll:token 0x60000bd+0x1be
```

What else should be changed to enable hot reload feature?